# Set Value on Combo Box

Tags: html, jsp

I have a simple code like this:

```
<select name="name">
       <option value="1">NAME A</option>
       <option value="2">NAME B</option>
       <option value="3">NAME C</option>
       <option value="4">NAME D</option>
       <option value="5">NAME E</option>  
</select>
```

I want make 1 more combo box like:

```
<select name="name2">
       <option value="var">var - NAME A</option>
       <option value="var">var - NAME B</option>
       <option value="var">var - NAME C</option>
</select>
```

So the question. If I select "NAME C" in first the combo box so the value is "3" and I want in the second combo box the value to become 4 (plus 1 from first combo box value) and means var is "4" in the second combo box. How to make the second combo box value always plus 1 from first combo box value?

Sorry for my bad English. Hope you get what I mean.

Comment: Which value in box 2 should match with box 1?

Comment: all var in box 2 should be same (actually not same but plus 1 from box 1) with box 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You need to take help of Javascript here.

    var name = document.getElementById("name").value; 
    // here you have value which is selected from combo box1

 var value2 = name+1; // here you are adding one to the value of combo box1
    document.getElementById("name2").value = value2; 
   // setting value to the combo box2
```

Comment: how to set value in combo box 2 ?

Comment: <select name="name" onchange="setCombo2()">
       <option value="1">NAME A</option>
       <option value="2">NAME B</option>
       <option value="3">NAME C</option>
       <option value="4">NAME D</option>
       <option value="5">NAME E</option>  
</select > <script> function setCombo2(){ var name1 = document.getElementById("name"); document.getElementById("name2").value=name1;}</script>

Answer (score 0):

Make the form like this

```
<select id="name" onchange="Change_Function()">
   <option value="1">NAME A</option>
   <option value="2">NAME B</option>
   <option value="3">NAME C</option>
   <option value="4">NAME D</option>
   <option value="5">NAME E</option>  
</select>
```

And in javascript

```
Change_Function(){
var val1 = document.getElementById("name").value; 
document.getElementById("name2").value = val1+1; 
}
```